# Create Custom Shipping Method with Live Rates Magento 2

Tags: custom, shipping-methods, magento2.2.6

I have to integrate one shipping method with Magento 2 site.

For this I am following below link to create custom shipping method, but it's for static rate.

https://magenticians.com/create-magento-2-shipping-module-method/

In my case I have to get available shipping rates and lables using API. Can anyone please help?

Comment: which shipping method you want to implement ?

Comment: I have to integrate Australiapost